# sqlfmt encountered an error: Could not parse SQL at position

Tags: sql, format, jinja2

I am working with sqlfmt to autoformat SQL code (with jinja templating).

I created a small statement, that is replacing quotes from two columns:

```
select
    replace(replace(fruit_name, '''', ''), '"', '') as fruit_name_without_quotes,
    replace(replace(fruit_group, '''', ''), '"', '') as fruit_group_without_quotes
from 
    {{ ref("dim_fruit") }}
```

Executing sqlfmt on this script results in the error:

```
sqlfmt encountered an error: Could not parse SQL at position 200: '") }}'
```

Funny enough, if I only select the first column, it works.

Any idea what to do here?

Thank you :)

I also tried disabling sqlfmt with `-- fmt: off`, but that hasn't worked.

Comment: `{{ ref("dim_fruit") }}` doesn't look very parseable, it's not valid SQL. Perhaps the templating is not working.

Comment: good point, but this is jinja-sql, which sqlfmt processes by design (see [sqlfmt documentation](https://pypi.org/project/shandy-sqlfmt/))

Comment: That could be, but something is not working in there somwehere, because the formatting doesn't appear to be processed properly

Comment: But this has nothing to do with the jinja code. You can also replace this with any other table indicator like ´table_schema.table_name´ and it still won't work. The SQL itself runs properly in the database.

Comment: So what error do you get *exatcly* when you do `from table_schema.table_name` without any jinja code?

Comment: It's the same as above:

`sqlfmt encountered an error: Could not parse SQL at position 200: '") }}'`